# dijit tree example

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

I've been trying to copy and paste dijit tree examples from the web that use the ajax.google.com version of dojo 1.7.2 and I cannot get anything to work.  Does anyone know of a single page whose source I can view, copy, and paste, and have a functional tree right away?  There are lots of examples of bits and pieces of trees (just the javascript, trees with dijit installed on a server, etc.) but nothing that anyone could copy and paste to get a fully functional tree.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although uses <1.7 syntax... its good for headstart as minor modifications need to be done for 1.7.2 version

http://dojocampus.com/explorer/#Dijit_Tree_Basic